# "Run a method only if a condition is satisfied" pattern

Tags: c#, attributes, decorator

I have a method

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting; // using visual studio's test framework

[TestMethod]
public void ATestMethod()
{
    // stuff
}
```

from a `public class ATestClass`. This test class runs two types of tests :

- tests requiring that a certain software is installed on the machine running the test
- tests that can run free

To handle this, I added a `public class BaseTestClass` from which I made `ATestClass` derive, and in `ATestClass` I added a :

```
public bool isTheSoftwareInstalledOnTheMachine()
{
    // stuff
}
```

and I "decorated" all internal scopes of tests from `ATestClass` as follows :

```
[TestMethod]
public void ATestMethod()
{
    if (isTheSoftwareInstalledOnTheMachine())
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

I find this horrible. I would rather like to be able to write something like :

```
[TestMethod]
[RunIfTheSoftwareInstalledOnTheMachine]
public void ATestMethod()
{
    // stuff
}
```

but I don't know if one is allowed to define "custom" `[characterizer]`'s. (I don't even know the right word for them.) If it is, would that be the best design ? (I heard about the decorator pattern, but I don't know if I could make it generic enough in my context, because I would potentially need to use the condition for many other test classes.) Anyway, how would I proceed with `characterizer`'s ?

Comment: That's called an attribute, and whether you can create a custom one that's respected by your unit testing framework depends on which framework you use.

Comment: @CodeCaster thx, I added the proper tag now that I know the name

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827091/Csharp-Attributes-in-minutes might be helpful

Comment: Anyway if you're using MSTest, you could put these tests in their own category, and then not run tests from that category. That's still a manual action though.

Comment: @Prasad no, the OP is not asking for an attribute tutorial. The test framework they use is not going to respect an attribute that the OP made up.

Comment: If you define your own attribute you surerly have to *check* for its existance on your own. You can´t expect your framework to guess what the attribute is for.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Well yeah, I don't expect magic to check it for me

Comment: @CodeCaster I am using the c# unit testing framework

Comment: There's no such thing, but I guess you're using MSTest. Look into test categories then.

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj There is no "**the** c# unit testing framework" - but I guess you are talkiing about NUnit?

Comment: @Fildor I used `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;` Is this `NUnit` ?

Comment: No, that's not NUnit. That's the framework that comes with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

I know you're using VS test framework but if you can change to NUnit you can accomplish what you want.

**Test case:**

```
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class MyAppTests
{
    [Test]
    [RunIfTheSoftwareInstalledOnTheMachine]
    public void ATestMethod()
    {
        // Executes if custom attribute is true, otherwise test case is ignored
    }
}
```

**Custom attribute:**

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using NUnit.Framework.Interfaces;

public class TestHelper
{
    public static bool IsTheSoftwareInstalledOnTheMachine()
    {
        // Return state of software
        return true;
    }
}

public class RunIfTheSoftwareInstalledOnTheMachineAttribute : Attribute, ITestAction
{
    public ActionTargets Targets { get; private set; }

    public void AfterTest(ITest test) {}

    public void BeforeTest(ITest test)
    {
        if (!TestHelper.IsTheSoftwareInstalledOnTheMachine())
        {
            Assert.Ignore("Omitting {0}. Software is not installed on machine.", test.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define your own attribute you surerly have to *check* for its existance on your own. You can´t expect your framework to guess what the attribute is for.

But I suppose you don´t even need an attribute to do this. You can simply ignore the test by putting the logic *inside* the test-method anyway:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    if(!RunIfTheSoftwareInstalledOnTheMachine)
        Assert.Ignore("Test not run because no software was installed");
    // your actual test-code
}
```

Another approach is to use the `CategoryAttribute` provided by NUnit, with which you can run only those tests that fall within your provided category:

```
[Test]
[Category("SoftwareInstalled")]
public void MyTest() { /* ... */ }
```

EDIT: You could also use the `TestCaseAttribute` with a specific method that returns a `TestCase` when the condition is met:

```
[TestCaseSource("ProvideTestcases")]
public void MyTest() { /* ... */ }

private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ProvideTestcases()
{
    if(RunIfTheSoftwareInstalledOnTheMachine)
        yield return new TestCaseData();
}
```

If the codition is not met no testcase is generated at all.

Comment: That's somehow what I am doing already, and that I mentioned finding horrible ... ?

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj IMO it´s not much more or less readable - and that is what you should allways strive for - than using an attribute.

Comment: What if I do want to use an attribute as I wrote in my question ?

Comment: You can only use the `CategoryAttribute`. There´s no way to make your testframework interpret what your own attribute is supposed to mean.

Comment: Why ? I mean, if I somehow define this new attribute somewhere (which is a part of my question) and if it's name doesn't clash with attributes from `NUnit`, why wouldn't `NUnit` interpret it correctly ?... By the way, I am NOT using `NUnit`, I am using the visual studio test framework, question updated

Comment: Anyway, this is not an answer to my question, as I want attributes

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj The answer to your question is "it´s not possible", or at least not in the way you want it. There are workarounds however, which I showed out. Only because you want something it doesn´t mean it´ll work.

Comment: I understand that your answer to my question is "it's not possible", and I am also aware that "wanting something doesn't make it possible" but I still don't see why it is not possible ? "There´s no way to make your testframework interpret what your own attribute is supposed to mean" --> fine, but why ? If I have a class, I can still design an attribute not clashing already existing attributes relative to the class, the visual studio test framework provides classes, why are those classes so special that designing "non clashinging" attributes for those classes is impossible.

Comment: (As you may know, because you say something is not possible doesn't make it impossible. That's why I am asking you why it is impossible.)

Comment: @ujsgeyrr1f0d0d0r0h1h0j0j_juj I already mentioned that the testframework has no knowledge on this attribute. You´d have to introduce some checks for that specific attribute *within the framework*, somethink like `if(attributeExists) ignoreTest()`. However `attributeExists` is completely out of the scope of the test-framework. How should it know what to do with something it doesn´t know?

Comment: I mean, I should be stupid for sure, but I don't get you : you wrote this earlier : "there´s no way to make your testframework interpret what your own attribute is supposed to mean". I stupidely understood that you meant "there´s no way to make your testframework interpret what your own attribute is supposed to mean, even you give a definition of `attributeExists`). Now I realized that you mean "there´s no way to make your testframework interpret what your own attribute is supposed to mean if you don't define your attribute", which is tautological, least to say...

Answer (score 0):

If the software being installed on the machine is a requirement for *any* of the tests to pass and any one test failing means the whole suite fails then why bother checking in multiple tests if the software is installed? Just write a *single* test to fail if the software is not installed and throw a useful exception. Something like:

```
[Test]
public void EnsureImportantSoftwareIsInstalled()
{
    if(!importantSoftwareIsInstalled)
    {
         Assert.Fail($"Software X must be installed for the tests in {nameof(MyTestClass)} to run, please install it");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want users (or worse, build machines) not having the software installed to have failed tests.

Comment: This by the does not answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

For Nunit 2.6, a slight variation of the HimBromBeere's answer works well for me. The test case is displayed as ignored.

```
[TestCaseSource("ProvideTestcases")]
public void MyTest() { /* ... */ }

private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ProvideTestcases()
{
    if(RunIfTheSoftwareInstalledOnTheMachine)
        yield return new TestCaseData().Ignore();
}
```